# Edit record from site.com

Tags: site.com

In site.com I have a page which iterates records of an object with data repeater.

I want to edit these records from this page ,but I didn't find anything to achieve this.

If there is any option to do this please help me to implement this.

Thanks

Comment: Ashish, it's unclear what you are asking. Try to be more specific, and add code where you think it can assist.

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce documentation about [Site.com Data Services](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_data_overview.htm&language=en_US) (a.k.a Siteforce) makes no mention of the ability to perform edits to data in this fashion.

The data connectors allow for retrieval of data to be displayed in site.com pages and the form elements allow for simple collection of information from site visitors to be stored in Standard or Custom Objects.